# Plugin to delete Outlook calendar birthdays VB.net

Tags: vb.net, calendar, outlook

I've been fighting with this one for a few days. I have been asked to create an Outlook plugin (for Outlook 2013) that will delete all birthdays that have been synced to the Outlook calendar by the CRM system that we use.

In my testing I have the plugin working so that it deletes some birthdays but not all. For testing, I am adding birthdays from 6 of my contacts to the calendar and when I run the plugin, it seems to only delete 4 or less at a time. I need to restart Outlook and have the plugin run again in order for more Birthdays to be deleted. The plugin runs on startup. I have also tested with a timer to wait 60 seconds and then try, but with the same result. I can't seem to get it to remove all appointments with "**Birthday**" in the subject.

Please see my code below.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private WithEvents _timer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()

    Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim lngDeletedAppointements As Long
    Dim objCalFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim strSubject As String



    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup        

        objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        objCalFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
        Dim objCalItems As Outlook.Items = objCalFolder.Items


        '******************************** Set Criteria for DELETION here ********************************
        strSubject = "Birthday"

        '************************************************************************************************

        'Get first appointment item   and store in 'appitem'
        Dim apptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = objCalItems.GetFirst

        'While appitem has appointments stored, if an appointment's subject contains "Birthday" delete it.
        Do While apptItem IsNot Nothing
            If apptItem.Subject.Contains(strSubject) Then
                apptItem.Delete()
                lngDeletedAppointements = lngDeletedAppointements + 1
            End If

            apptItem = objCalItems.GetNext
        Loop

        'Display Messagebox informing how many birthdays were deleted
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(lngDeletedAppointements.ToString + " Birthdays deleted.", "DELETE Birthdays")

        'Cleanup
        objNamespace = Nothing
        objCalFolder = Nothing
        objCalItems = Nothing
        apptItem = Nothing
        lngDeletedAppointements = Nothing
        strSubject = Nothing
    End Sub
```

I am using a **Do While** loop for the deletion process because I have read that using a **For Each** loop would cause the indexing in the collection to get messed up and only about half of the items in the collection would actually be deleted (I have tried this as well).The **Do While** loop seems to provide the same results. I'm so confused!

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. I feel like this should be so simple but of-course it never is! I am very new to plugin development,  and am still a pretty junior programmer. Please let me know if any additional info is needed an I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried a decrementing a 'For' loop like,

```
For value as Integer = objCalItems.Count to 0 Step -1
    apptItem = objCalItems(value)

    If apptItem.Subject.Contains(strSubject) Then
        apptItem.Delete()
        lngDeletedAppointements = lngDeletedAppointements + 1
    Else
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(apptItem)
    End If
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: THIS TOTALLY WORKED! Thanks so much Insane... I did have to change one piece. I needed to change `Integer = objCalItems.Count To 0 Step -1` to`Integer = objCalItems.Count To` **`1`** `Step -1`. It was throwing an **Array Index Out of Bounds** exception. This was an enormous help. I am also looking into the **Marshal** class as I most certainly don't use it enough. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. I read that when you delete an item say Item 3, Outlook moves the 4th item to position 3. Hence we end up scanning lesser items :P. The approach you are using now iterates over all the calendar items which can be very expensive if there are a lot of items in your calendar. I would suggest that you make use of **Items.Restrict** as Eugene has pointed out. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over all items in the folder use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to find Outlook items that correspond to you conditions. For example, take a look at the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Comment: Thanks for this as well Eugene I'm always looking to be as efficient as possible!